# Where can I find official data on character frame data and hitboxes?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

In super street fighter 4, people often talk about frame data and hit boxes, and technical details about these topics can be found online.

Has Capcom ever released these information? Or are they simply from guesswork and deductions by players?

Comment: its not guess work.  people have broken the game down to figure them out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SF4/SSF4 in particular, no comprehensive official frame data or hitbox information has ever been released that I know of.

There are often "official" guide books that will include frame data information, but even in those cases, the frame data for those guides are typically calculated by hand via recording the gameplay and frame-stepping the video in order to count frames, and doesn't come directly from Capcom. It's not usually too complicated to compile frame data this way, actually, it's just time-consuming. Many dedicated players have helped compile frame data and error-check existing data in the same way. [Here's a good video that gives an overview of the process.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9fUeFyHu3c)

Capcom has shown hitboxes directly in very limited instances, such as [on their blog where they illustrate changes they made for SSF4 Arcade Edition](http://www.capcom.co.jp/blog/sf4/development_blog/2011/01/18_3002.html). Unofficial hitbox demonstrations that you may find around the internet in picture [or video form](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFluH4JLMl0) were actually derived by mining the hit box data from the game files themselves and overlaying the resulting boxes onto sample character footage.